# A question about propagation delay

Tags: logic-gates

A gate has a propagation delay of 20ns, we know that if we apply  a input signal whose duration is less that 20ns , that signal will not change the output state of the gate, similarly, if the duration is more than 20ns, the output will change. But how about when the duration is exactly 20ns? Will it change the output?

Comment: your first sentence is plain wrong. That's not what a propagation delay means. So, your whole question is based on an incorrect understanding of "delay", and we've got really nothing to answer but "please research properly what a propagation delay is, and your question will answer itself".

Comment: @Marcus Müller where I've written the definition of the propagation delay? the statement which I've written was a statement which is "about" propagation delay. And that statement might be wrong. I didn't write what propagation delay is at all.

Comment: The big question here is, is this scenario a real or purely ideal one? Propagation delay has a definition which makes more sense in real applications.

Comment: @Sayan I didn't write you gave a definition of propagation delay, I said you made an incorrect assumption on what it is, and your question is based on that.

Comment: @Sayan Maybe you mean rise time, not propagation delay?

Comment: you are conflating propogation, risetime and setup-and-hold

Comment: Oh boy!  As Marcus says, your first wandering sentence is wrong on all levels.  It takes 20 ns for the input to propogate to a change in the output.  Removing the input 15ns does not mean the output does not change, rather the odds are significant that the output will glitch.  You are violating hold times.

Answer (score 4):

A propagation delay of 20 ns means that the output takes 20 ns to respond to an input.  It does not mean that it will not respond to an input pulse less than 20 ns wide. In any case, nothing magical will happen with an exact (how exacc?) 20 ns pulse.

Comment: so it means if I apply the signal for say, 5ns, the output will still change, but will take 20ns to change . is it correct?

Comment: @Sayan Theoretically you can say that the 5 ns signal will appear at the output after 20 ns. But in a real gate, probability is that the shorter width signal is more like a glitch to the gate, is "swallowed" by the gate. Output may change at the gate but not change/rise "enough" to read it as '1' by the the logic which is being driven by the gate.

Answer (score 2):

*A gate has a propagation delay of 20ns, we know that if we apply a input signal whose duration is less that 20ns , that signal will not change the output state of the gate*

Not really, many gates have more than one stage (logic + buffer). If a two stage gate has two 10 ns delays, then a 15 ns pulse would get through. Also, rise and fall times are finite which further complicate your assumptions.

*But how about when the duration is exactly 20ns?*

Hard to determine. But for a one stage gate, there will be a point near 20 ns where you will get a runt pulse out.

Answer (score 2):

Are we talking about the real world or the theoretical world? In the real world the actual propagation delay may depend on temperature and voltage.

There's also noise and jitter. So, an exact 20ns pulse becomes a statistical occurrence.

The net result is that a 'real' system would become unreliable. Sometimes it might work, other times it might not. Heat it - works, cool it, nope. If the datasheet says 20ns, you'd design the system to tolerate a slightly greater value.

Answer (score 1):

> A gate has a propagation delay of 20ns, we know that if we apply a input signal whose duration is less that 20ns , that signal will not change the output state of the gate

That is not what propagation delay is. A signal may or may not change the output if the signal lasts less than the propagation delay.

A signal is not guaranteed to change the output if minimum *hold* time (and for edge-triggered circuits, *set-up* time) are not met.

> similarly, if the duration is more than 20ns, the output will change.

That is similarly incorrect. The hold time (and for edge-triggered circuits, set-up time) may be longer or shorter than the propagation delay.

> But how about when the duration is exactly 20ns? Will it change the output?

The behavior is usually undefined. Pulses that are shorter than required by specifications (i.e. the data-sheet) may or may not cause changes in the output.

Comment: The OP is talking about logic gates. "setup and hold" are for synchronous elements.

Comment: Minimum hold time is still applicable to simple logic gates. Minimum hold time can never be longer than propagation delay for a simple gate, but it can be less. With single transistor gates, they are likely to be the same. However, if the gate has extra "drive" circuitry, for example a totem-pole output, it could easily happen that propagation delay is 20 nSec, but a 19 nSec pulse causes a "glitch" (short pulse) in the output.

Comment: I specifically frowned at "setup". Hold is right. The input has to be "held" for a minimal time at a gate input.

Comment: @MituRaj You are correct, setup time is generally a requirement for edge triggered circuits, and not simple gates.

Answer (score 1):

**The minimum pulse width to reach the threshold is NOT the true propagation delay but perhaps the minimum propagation delay under unknown conditions.**

**Setup and Hold times are the pre- and post- times for data relative to the clock edge to guarantee accurate data is latched which is NOT propagation delay of a flip flop but may include tPD for the data driver.**

Prop. delay may include errors on slow input rise times and unknown load for output rise time and variations in supply, temperature and threshold tolerances in manufacturing. So to verify specs, you must use the same conditions. If you need better specs, then you must control the load with lower capacitance, or higher output current to reach threshold, e.g. 3.6V logic is faster than 5.5 or 6V logic due to the driver resistance being ~ 25 ohms vs 50 Ohms +/-25%.

Consider the 74HC14 Schmitt trigger which has hysteresis and these input thresholds change with Vdd, temperature. The output rise time is rated for a standard load capacitance due to RdsOn*C= T (tau).

This is an example of
the normal way to define input pulse trigger threshold test conditions.

- IC=?  load = ? pF, at Vdd= ? at temp.= ?'C , input source = ? Vmax=? Tr= ? 10% to 90%  Source impedance =?

  - unless just measuring from Vdd/2 input to output for some asymmetrical logic levels, we simply call with 50% pulse width or  **PW50** as the pulse width at 50%  of supply rail levels .

Here is the standard method of measuring logic Prop. delay. (rise or fall delay time which assumes the input reaches threshold)

[image]